# How to find the output when using an extremely large input in this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci, pseudocode, puzzle

During an interview I was given the following problem:

From the following puzzle, what would the output of puzzle(power(2022, 100)) be?

```
 
function puzzle(N) {
   A, B, C, D = 1, 1, 1, 1
  .repeat N times {
     X = D + 2 * C + 3 * B + 4 * A
     a, b, c, d = b, c, d, x
  }
   return D % 10000000000 
}
```

From looking at the puzzle and by implementing it on my language of choice, I found out that it forms some kind of Fibonacci sequence. However, the code didn't finish running so it was impossible to me to find the output. I answered that the code could be refactored as a sum of fibs to optimize the output but I wasn't able to do it, however, the interviewer said it was a correct reasoning in the right path (he gave me some more time to crack it but I simply failed).

Now, I'm still feeling curious about it, even after failing the interviewer. Could I get some insight?

edit: thanks to the accepted answer I hacked a solution in Python (apart from the one included in the answer update), here's the code if someone is curious:

```
#reimplemented in python because Ruby is a real pain to work with matrices

def matrix_pow(matrix, power, modulus):
    # Initialize result to the identity matrix of the same size as matrix
    result = [[int(i == j) for j in range(len(matrix))] for i in range(len(matrix))]
    while power > 0:
        # If the current bit of the exponent is 1, multiply result by matrix
        if power % 2 == 1:
            result = matrix_multiply(result, matrix, modulus)
        # Square matrix and divide power by 2
        matrix = matrix_multiply(matrix, matrix, modulus)
        power //= 2
    # Return the result
    return result

# This function multiplies two matrices modulo a given modulus
def matrix_multiply(matrix1, matrix2, modulus):
    # Initialize result to a matrix of the appropriate size filled with zeros
    result = [[0] * len(matrix2[0]) for _ in range(len(matrix1))]
    # Perform matrix multiplication
    for i in range(len(matrix1)):
        for j in range(len(matrix2[0])):
            for k in range(len(matrix2)):
                result[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j]
                result[i][j] %= modulus
    # Return the result
    return result

# This function solves the puzzle
def puzzle(n):
    # Initialize matrix M
    M = [[0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 1],
         [4, 3, 2, 1]]
    # Calculate M^n modulo 10^10
    M_pow = matrix_pow(M, n, 10**10)
    # Initialize vector v
    v = [1, 1, 1, 1]
    # Multiply M^n by v to get the solution
    result = matrix_multiply(M_pow, [[x] for x in v], 10**10)
    # Return the element in the fourth row and first column of the result
    return result[3][0]

print(puzzle(10))
# output 30520
print(puzzle(100))
# outputs 720820623
print(puzzle(2022**100))
# outputs 2436815984
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you know what matrices are and [matrix multiplication](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html)

At all points the status of the puzzle can be written as a column vector like this:

```
[A]
[B]
[C]
[D]
```

After one step it can be written as:

```
[B]    [0 1 0 0]    [A]
[C] -- [0 0 1 0] \/ [B]
[D] -- [0 0 0 1] /\ [C]
[X]    [4 3 2 1]    [D]
```

We can write the right hand side as `M * v` where `M` is that 4x4 transition matrix, and `v` is the vertical vector.

After `N` steps we get `M^N * v`.  We know our starting vector `v`.  And we know how to pick the answer.  We just need a good way to get `M^N`.

And for that, well, there is a trick.  It isn't hard to work out the series `M, M^2, M^4, M^8, ...`.  And with that series and the base 2 representation of `2022^100` you can figure out the answer to the puzzle.  Unfortunately the numbers will get very long.  But if you do all calculations modulo 10000000000  (meaning you multiply, then take `% 10000000000` to get the remainder), then they stay reasonable and you can generate the answer.

The connection with Fibonacci is that it is computed by a 2x2 transition matrix and you can to identical logic.  But I doubt that there is a way to get from Fibonacci to this.

Incidentally I consider this a fun problem, but not a very good interview question.  Because the arbitrary skill that it tests for is not very well correlated with most programming work that you might have to do.

---

Here is a Python version.  I verified that it agrees with the naive approach for powers up to 100.

```
class ModuloValue:
    def __init__ (self, n, m):
        self.modulo = m
        self.value = n % m

    def __int__ (self):
        return self.value

    def __add__ (self, other):
        return ModuloValue(self.value + int(other), self.modulo)

    def __mul__ (self, other):
        return ModuloValue(self.value * int(other), self.modulo)

    def __str__ (self):
        return str(self.value)

class Matrix:
    def __init__ (self, rows):
        self.rows = rows

    def value (self, i, j):
        return self.rows[i][j]

    def __add__ (self, other):
        rows1 = self.rows
        rows2 = other.rows
        rows_out = []
        for i in range(len(rows1)):
            row = []
            for j in range(len(rows1[0])):
                row.append(rows1[i][j] + rows2[i][j])
            rows_out.append(row)
        return Matrix(rows_out)

    def __mul__ (self, other):
        rows1 = self.rows
        rows2 = other.rows
        rows_out = []
        for i in range(len(rows1)):
            row = []
            for k in range(len(rows2[0])):
                value = rows1[i][0] * rows2[0][k]
                for j in range(1, len(rows1[0])):
                    value = value + rows1[i][j] * rows2[j][k]
                row.append(value)
            rows_out.append(row)
        return Matrix(rows_out)

    def __str__ (self):
        answer = '['
        for row in self.rows:
            answer += '\n  [' + ', '.join((str(x) for x in row)) + ']'
        return answer + '\n]'

    def pow (self, n):
        power = self
        answer = None
        while 0 < n:
            if 1 == n % 2:
                if answer is None:
                    answer = power
                else:
                    answer = answer * power
            power = power * power
            n = n // 2
        return answer

mod = 10000000000
rows = [
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [4, 3, 2, 1],
]
for i in range(len(rows)):
    rows[i] = [ModuloValue(x, mod) for x in rows[i]]
m = Matrix(rows)
m_pow = m.pow(2022**100)
v = [[1], [1], [1], [1]]
print((m_pow * Matrix(v)).rows[3][0])
```

Comment: Hmm, very insightful tbh. It certainly crossed my mind that it had something to do with matrix exponentiation (thought of modular exponentiation first), but yeah, it really was above my level of knowledgment (2nd year compsci student). Curiously, the interview was for a standard backend job at a newspaper website, surprising they thought of this question(and yes, probably not correlated with the daily tasks of the job lol). 

Anyways, I tried coding another solution following your answer without luck. Be free to post an implementation if you thought of any, will accept your answer anyway.

Comment: @LautaroGraciani I added a straightforward implementation.  The answer it found is `2436815984`. As for the question, it is an anti-pattern.  "We want smart people. I'll ask a question only smart people can answer!" That selects for a specific kind of person which is NOT necessarily what you need.